# Incremented variable within nested views

Tags: php, laravel

In the laravel framework, I have several nested views as follows

```
<mainview>
  loop @include <sub-view>
    loop @include <sub-sub-view>
```

I would like to keep a counter of just how many sub-sub-views there are. It becomes, in effect, a row counter. I am not sure where to declare/init this variable ($sub-sub-view-counter), and where to increment it along the way. No matter where I put it, it can't be seen and incremented by every view.

Comment: Two things tried:
1. View::share('var',$var) - all views could see the var, but I could not increment $var and have the new value visible to parent

2. with('var'=>$var) - again, all views could see $var, but it would remain untouched as seen by parent

Comment: do you need the nesting level or number of includes?

Comment: on each sub-sub-view I need a counter that reflects its ordinal position across the whole main-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is maybe a bit of a hack, but unless nothing better comes up...

You will need either a *helper* function or an *object* (easiest way is to put that to the models). For demonstration I chose the object variant, as I believe it's a bit easier to handle and most of all easier to extend to your needs. Also this implicitly supports multiple counters, as the value is saved per-object (You'd have to jump through a few hoops to get this functionality with a function).

```
class Counter
{
    private $count = 0;

    public function inc()
    {
        return ++$this->count;
    }
}
```

So for this specific implementation you will have to create it *somewhere*. You can either put a line like this in your parent view somewhere before including your sub-views, or inject it from PHP with the `with()` method.

```
<?php $counter = new Counter(); ?>
```

You include the sub-view like usual (remember to use `include`, not `render`, to keep the `$counter`variable) I used a `for` loop for testing, but you can of course use any variant you want.

```
@for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    @include('home.sub')
@endfor
```

And finally you can just call this in the sub-view

```
<span>{{ $counter->inc() }}</span>
```

You can easily extend this model with a factory to get counter values from anywhere in your application, but for your use case this basic variant should be enough.